# Cypress finding DOM element using multiple contains

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

I need to select the first email in the list, but I don't know when it arrives.

Setting a large timeout for the email to arrive would probably work, but I am looking for a better solution.

I need to select the first row where the `.subject` is `confirm your email address` and the time field is `a few seconds ago`.

This is what I've tried:

```
cy.contains('a few seconds ago')
  .closest('.row') // get the container
  .contains('confirm your email address')
```

The issue with this solution is that in case there is an email with a subject `reset your password`, it will find it first, then wait for the last contains to timeout.

**It seems `Cypress` does not recheck the entire call chain**, just the last that it fails. (so it does not restart from the first `.get('a few seconds ago')`, but only waits until the `.contains('confirm your email address')` times out.

I could also run some `jquery` checks, but then I am on my own writing timeouts and retries, which is a no-go in `Cypress`...

How do I make `Cypress` find the first row where both `contains` requirements are met?

[image: Mailhog UI]

---

Edit:

If I write multiple assertions inside the `should`:

```
  cy.get(".msglist-message", { timeout: 10_000 })
    .should(($row) => {
      // either fails triggers retry
      expect($row.text()).to.match(/a few seconds ago/i);
      expect($row.text()).to.match(new RegExp(subject, "i"));
    })
    .click();
```

the `click()` will still have references on all the rows (that matched `.msglist-message`), which is unexpected to me:

> `cy.click()` can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 7 elements. Pass `{ multiple: true }` if you want to serially click each element

So basically I just asserted that there is a row that matches a `row` given my multiple `contains` criteria, but I still cannot use `Cypress` commands on it, like `click`, I don't have a reference on that element.

It also seems that `should` [cannot yield a new value with lambda](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#The-current-subject-is-yielded).

When I tried to click inside the `should`, I got some endless retry loop:

```
  cy.get(".msglist-message", { timeout: 10_000 })
    .should(($row) => {
      // either fails triggers retry
      expect($row.text()).to.match(/a few seconds ago/i);
      expect($row.text()).to.match(new RegExp(subject, "i"));

      cy.wrap($row).click()
    })
```

[image: Cypress error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps reversing the order catches it?

```js
cy.contains('confirm your email address')
  .closest('.row') // get the container
  .contains('a few seconds ago')          // do you even need this? timeout === 4 seconds
```

Otherwise, `.should(() => expect()...)` will retry

```js
cy.get('.row')
  .should($row => {
    // either fails triggers retry
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/a few seconds ago/i)
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/confirm your email address/i)
  })
```

**Narrowing down the row list**

As you mentioned, `.should()` does not change the subject so subsequent chain sees all the rows.

To narrow it down, follow with a `.contains()` that selects a single row

```js
cy.contains('.row', 'Confirm your email address')
  .should($row => {
    // either fails triggers retry
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/a few seconds ago/i)
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/confirm your email address/i)
  })
  .contains('.row', 'Confirm your email address') 
  .click()
```

or you can apply the `.contains()` at the top

```js
cy.contains('.row', 'Confirm your email address')
  .should($row => {
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/a few seconds ago/i)
  })
  .click()
```

or (logically) the message received "a few seconds ago" will be the one at the top

```js
cy.contains('.row', 'Confirm your email address')
  .should($row => {
    // either fails triggers retry
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/a few seconds ago/i)
    expect($row.text()).to.match(/confirm your email address/i)
  })
  .eq(0) 
  .click()
```

Comment: I think something like this is going to be the way, I just cannot `click()` on the item using `Cypress`.  I still cannot have a reference to the DOM element using this method. You can see my edit.

Comment: Reversing the order did not catch it, I wanted to make the test more reliable. The first time I tried it happened there were multiple rows with `a few seconds ago`, I guess this may be shown for some more duration than actually couple seconds.